# Jquery function looping (flowtext) for carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc-4, bootstrap-4

I have an issue. I have a carousel with many images and text on it. To make the text responsive I am using a script called FlowText. It works perfectly on the first carousel image(the active one) but as soon as it moves, it doesn't. I am suspecting its because ... it runs only once, and when you move the carousel it doesn't anymore. How would you actually do that so that it works everytime you move the carousel.

```
<div id="imageCarousel3" class="carousel slide" data-interval="2000"
 data-ride="carousel" data-pause="hover" data-wrap="true">

 <ol class="carousel-indicators">
 <li data-target="#imageCarousel3" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
 <li data-target="#imageCarousel3" data-slide-to="1"></li>
 <li data-target="#imageCarousel3" data-slide-to="2"></li>
 <li data-target="#imageCarousel3" data-slide-to="3"></li>
 <li data-target="#imageCarousel3" data-slide-to="4"></li>
 <li data-target="#imageCarousel3" data-slide-to="5"></li>
 <li data-target="#imageCarousel3" data-slide-to="6"></li>
 <li data-target="#imageCarousel3" data-slide-to="7"></li>
 <li data-target="#imageCarousel3" data-slide-to="8"></li>
 <li data-target="#imageCarousel3" data-slide-to="9"></li>
 <li data-target="#imageCarousel3" data-slide-to="10"></li>
 <li data-target="#imageCarousel3" data-slide-to="11"></li>
 <li data-target="#imageCarousel3" data-slide-to="12"></li>
 <li data-target="#imageCarousel3" data-slide-to="13"></li>
 <li data-target="#imageCarousel3" data-slide-to="14"></li>
 </ol>


<div class="carousel-inner" style=" max-width: 946px;  overflow: hidden; margin:0 auto;">

    <div class="item active" ;">
        <img src="/Content/Images/Slide21.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        <div id="flowtext1"  style="width: 50%; height:100%; top:0px; right:0px; position:absolute; background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75); ">
            <div class="carousel-caption"  style="top:0%; position:absolute;">
                <p style="font-family:'Open Sans Light'; font-size:1.9em; text-align:center; left:20%;"><strong>DSM e-FRE</strong></p>
                <p style="font-family:'Open Sans Light';font-size:1.5em; text-align :center;"><strong>Freight Management Systems</strong></p>
            </div>
                <div class="carousel-caption" style="top:30%; left: 10%; position:absolute;">
                    <ul style="text-align:left; left:0%;">
                        <li style="font-family:'Open Sans Light';font-size:1.2em; text-align:left;"><strong>NVOCC</strong><br /><br /></li>
                        <li style="font-family:'Open Sans Light';font-size:1.2em; text-align:left;"><strong>Freight Consolidation</strong><br /><br /></li>
                        <li style="font-family:'Open Sans Light';font-size:1.2em; text-align:left;"><strong>Staff Transparency</strong><br /><br /></li>
                        <li style="font-family:'Open Sans Light';font-size:1.2em; text-align:left;"><strong>No Missed Billings</strong></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <img src="~/Content/Images/Slide22.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        <div id="flowtext1" style="width: 50%; height:100%; top:0px; right:0px; position:absolute; background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75); ">
            <div class="carousel-caption" style="top:0%; position:absolute;">
                <p style="font-family:'Open Sans Light'; font-size:1.9em; text-align:center; left:20%;"><strong>DSM e-HMS</strong></p>
                <p style="font-family:'Open Sans Light';font-size:1.4em; text-align :center;"><strong>Haulage Management Systems</strong></p>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-caption" style="top:30%; left:10%; position:absolute;">
                <ul style="text-align:left;">
                    <li style="font-family:'Open Sans Light';font-size:1.2em; text-align:left;"><strong>Haulage Movement Optimization & Advanced Electronic Planning</strong><br /><br /></li>
                    <li style="font-family:'Open Sans Light';font-size:1.2em; text-align:left;"><strong>Map Interface and Telemetrics</strong><br /><br /></li>
                    <li style="font-family:'Open Sans Light';font-size:1.2em; text-align:left;"><strong>e-HR (Driver Payroll Auto-Calc)</strong><br /><br /></li>
                    <li style="font-family:'Open Sans Light';font-size:1.2em; text-align:left;"><strong>Trailer Audit and Control</strong></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And for the scripts part

```
 @section scripts{
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.fittext.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/flowtype.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#flowtext1").flowtype();

    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#fittext1").fitText();
        $("#fittext2").fitText(1.2);
        $("#fittext3").fitText(1.1, { minFontSize: '10px', maxFontSize: '75px' });
    </script>


}
```

And here are the attached pictures. First one works fine. 2nd does not resize.

[First Picture Carousel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJLBa.png)

[Second Picture Carousel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJgYO.png)

EDIT: Changed from id to class as suggested.

Not working as intended anymore though. Even in normal size (desktop) it is super small now. Except for the first slide.

Any help ?

[New Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7pam.png)

[New Image second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dz5Ib.png)

Comment: You have 2 elements with the same ID(`flowtext1`), which is wrong. Use class there

Comment: Ahh I see. Thanks. I edited my post, there is still a hiccup. Do you know what might be happening ?

Comment: I tried giving each of them a different id, but that did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to looping the particular script.

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var intervalFunction = setInterval(function () {
                    $(".flowtext1").flowtype();
                }, 500);
            });
</script>
```

This will loop said jscript flowtype every 0.5 sec. Thus, when sliding to a new slide, it will just resize the text.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have two elements with the same ID. Using jQuery ID selector -> `$("#something")....` returns the first element with that ID because it assumes that it should be unique. One way to fix your problem is to use `class` and not `id`.

HTML:

```
<div class="item active" ;">
        <img src="/Content/Images/Slide21.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        <div class="flowtext"  style="width: 50%; height:100%; top:0px; right:0px; position:absolute; background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75); ">
            <div class="carousel-caption"  style="top:0%; position:absolute;">
                <p style="font-family:'Open Sans Light'; font-size:1.9em; text-align:center; left:20%;"><strong>DSM e-FRE</strong></p>
                <p style="font-family:'Open Sans Light';font-size:1.5em; text-align :center;"><strong>Freight Management Systems</strong></p>
            </div>
                <div class="carousel-caption" style="top:30%; left: 10%; position:absolute;">
                    <ul style="text-align:left; left:0%;">
                        <li style="font-family:'Open Sans Light';font-size:1.2em; text-align:left;"><strong>NVOCC</strong><br /><br /></li>
                        <li style="font-family:'Open Sans Light';font-size:1.2em; text-align:left;"><strong>Freight Consolidation</strong><br /><br /></li>
                        <li style="font-family:'Open Sans Light';font-size:1.2em; text-align:left;"><strong>Staff Transparency</strong><br /><br /></li>
                        <li style="font-family:'Open Sans Light';font-size:1.2em; text-align:left;"><strong>No Missed Billings</strong></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <img src="~/Content/Images/Slide22.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        <div class="flowtext" style="width: 50%; height:100%; top:0px; right:0px; position:absolute; background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75); ">
            <div class="carousel-caption" style="top:0%; position:absolute;">
                <p style="font-family:'Open Sans Light'; font-size:1.9em; text-align:center; left:20%;"><strong>DSM e-HMS</strong></p>
                <p style="font-family:'Open Sans Light';font-size:1.4em; text-align :center;"><strong>Haulage Management Systems</strong></p>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-caption" style="top:30%; left:10%; position:absolute;">
                <ul style="text-align:left;">
                    <li style="font-family:'Open Sans Light';font-size:1.2em; text-align:left;"><strong>Haulage Movement Optimization & Advanced Electronic Planning</strong><br /><br /></li>
                    <li style="font-family:'Open Sans Light';font-size:1.2em; text-align:left;"><strong>Map Interface and Telemetrics</strong><br /><br /></li>
                    <li style="font-family:'Open Sans Light';font-size:1.2em; text-align:left;"><strong>e-HR (Driver Payroll Auto-Calc)</strong><br /><br /></li>
                    <li style="font-family:'Open Sans Light';font-size:1.2em; text-align:left;"><strong>Trailer Audit and Control</strong></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".flowtext").flowtype();
 </script>
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks, i changed the id to class but ... now it not really working as intended. I edited my post